# Android phonegap app: open link from browser into app

Tags: android, cordova

I'm building a phonegap app which will install on android.

I want to somehow allow sharing features on twitter, etc. So you could create a 'post' in the app and people can share it on twitter probably linking to a domain containing the post.

Is there any way in phonegap to allow this link from say twitter (in a browser), to open in the installed app version?

The installed app follows the same url combinations as the web version.

Answer (score 1):

My tutorial: [TMT5P1](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt5p1) lets the user log in to their twitter account from the app. Then they can tweet, see tweets, mentions, etc from the PhoneGap / Android app. Twitter actions are integrated into the app, instead of making the user leave the app to go to twitter website.

Requires child browser plugin for secure login.

Comment: This is very helpful but not exactly what I'm looking for, If a person is in their twitter or fb app, or even viewing their twitter or fb through browser, and a link is shared I would like them to be able to click the link from twitter or fb and have the option to open it in my app (or in browser). I've seen the functionality with other (probably native) apps but not yet on cordova.